# Alternative method in Rails 4 for RawUrlEncode PHP method

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, url, methods, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know if it is a dumb question, but I searched and I can't found a method like this in Ruby on Rails 4. I need a method like [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) of PHP, but for Ruby on Rails 4.

**From PHP Documentation:**

```
Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_.~ have 
been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits. 
This is the encoding described in » RFC 3986 for protecting literal characters
from being interpreted as special URL delimiters, and for protecting URLs from 
being mangled by transmission media with character conversions (like some email
systems).
```

So, there's a method like this in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about URI::escape method?

```
URI::escape('google.com/?q=what an awesome day')
```

The method above escapes the input string, replacing all unsafe characters with codes. That is, it encodes the input using percent-encoding. You can read more about percent encoding:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Thanks Yosep! Can you give more details to other people that have the same question? Just add some details and I will give you the best answer. Again, thanks, solved my problem!